# Liking and sharing on Facebook with a callback

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a small product where the PO asked for the possibility for an end-user to like a facebook page and share on their timeline. Every time a user does this, an action should happen.

For my prototype, I used the Facebook sharer, however, this doesn't fire a callback once the share happens, which means the "reward" for sharing can't be distributed honestly and fairly. The same problem applies to liking a page.

Is there a way for me to receive a callback signal (preferably in JS) once I like/share a Facebook page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewarding users for sharing or liking is not allowed. That is why they removed the possibility to get a callback for sharing. The only way to (seriously) check if a user liked a Page is to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permission, but you would not get it approved in the review process for something that is not allowed, obviously. Facebook even removed the possibility to get a callback after liking a Page, but that would be pointless anyway - you could always go to that Page on facebook.com and remove your like.

Either way, the main point is that it is not allowed:

> 4.4 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Awesome, at least I have a clear source to give to my product owner! Thanks!